# Please help interpret the transaction action steps in this flash loan transaction

Tags: transactions, blockchain, ethereum, etherscan

I would like some assistance in interpreting the transaction steps from this flash loan.  Obviously this was executed due to a % gain analysis.  Can we determine from the actions, what is the % difference/gain and the actual profit, then deducting the transaction and gas fees?

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x364d7b9c32c8b5eb6bc93a8f838b56a2ee9e64b984adf2c4809e9a5566fdefa2
[image]